# Fire Process based on change in Time on Date/Time

Tags: process-builder, datetime

I have a process that needs to send an email reminder any time a date/time field (Send_Reminder_to_WM_On__c) is changed. However, because the process has to have scheduled actions, I cannot use the "ISCHANGED" value for the field. I have been trying to circumvent this by building a custom criteria, using the code below.

```
OR(

ISBLANK([Task].Send_Reminder_to_WM_On__c) = FALSE,

AND(
TEXT(PRIORVALUE([Task].Send_Reminder_to_WM_On__c)) <> 
TEXT([Task].Send_Reminder_to_WM_On__c),
ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE([Task].Send_Reminder_to_WM_On__c )) = FALSE
)

)
```

The process works if the Send_Reminder_to_WM_On__c field is cleared, saved, and a new value is entered, but simply changing the value from one date/time value to another does not launch the process.

Is there a way to achieve the desired results via the criteria formula?

Comment: did you try with workflow rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by changing the criteria to the following:

[image]

The formula in condition 2 is:

```
PRIORVALUE([Task].Send_Reminder_to_WM_on__c)
```

I seemed to be overthinking the problem my first time around!